# How to use term_group for ordering subcategories in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to customize the order for subcategories listed in a navigation bar in Wordpress.  The codex makes it clear that there are five ways to do this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Parameters. I am limited to two: 1) prefixing each category with a number and 2) using term_group.  The problem is that the Codex seems to be pretty vague as to how to make use of term_group as it only describes it as a group of terms. I know that a category containing the word, "video," always needs to be placed first, a category containing the word, "roster," always must come second, etc. Is there a way to achieve this without prefixing the slug and possibly using term_group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin that does that:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/order-categories/

Comment: I'm positively amazed that still works considering the plugin hasn't been updated since May, 2008. Sort categories and subcategories. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

To do this generically for terms (with custom taxonomies), you can use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-menu-order